# How to change the working directory on Slurm

Tags: python, cluster-computing, slurm, cd, pwd

I am working on a slurm cluster where I am running couple of jobs. It is hard for me to check the jobs one by one in each directory.

I could manage to check in which directory the jobs are running using

```
scontrol show job JOB_ID
```

This command gives me various lines on the output. Few of them are listed below

```
   OverSubscribe=OK Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
   Command=/home/astha/vt-st/scf-test/303030/49/qsub.job
   WorkDir=/home/astha/vt-st/scf-test/303030/49
   StdErr=/home/astha/vt-st/scf-test/303030/49/qsub.job.e1205
   StdIn=/dev/null
   StdOut=/home/astha/vt-st/scf-test/303030/49/qsub.job.o1205
   Power=
   MailUser=(null) MailType=NONE
```

Where WorkDir (this is an example, the path will be different for each job) from above output is the directory in which I want to switch.

then

```
cd /home/astha/vt-st/scf-test/303030/49
```

But typing this long commands make my fingers cry.

I have tried to make a small python script to print scontrol show job

```
# Try block
try:
    # Take a number
        print("scontrol show job")


# Exception block
except (ValueError):
  # Print error message
  print("Enter a numeric value")
```

But then how I should improve it so that it takes my given input number and then grep the WorkDir from the output and change the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to have a python script change your current working directory easily, and can do it simply in Bash like this:

```
$ cdjob() { cd $(squeue -h -o%Z -j "$1") ; }
```

This will create a Bash function named `cdjob` that accept a job ID as parameter. You can check it was created correctly with

```
$ type cdjob
cdjob is a function
cdjob ()
{
    cd $(squeue -h -o%Z -j "$1")
}
```

After you run the above command (which you can place in your startup script `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` if you want it to survive logouts) you will be able to do

```
$ cdjob 22078365
```

and this will bring you to the working directory of job `22078365` for instance. You see that rather than trying to parse the output of `scontrol` I am using the output formatting options of `squeue` to simply output the needed information.

Comment: Thank you Sir, It partly worked for me. It prints the path (example "cd /path/of/cd/directory/" but do not change it automatically.

Comment: hum yes sorry I left an `echo` in there for testing. I updated the answer